# Replacing column value which has special characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has column and is inserted with data and in the data there are some characters for example

output should be like this

```
column name :Name   
value 1: andrew-jr  
value 2 :john-doctor
```

but I am getting it as

```
Name     
andrewâ€jr  
johnâ€doctor
```

The `-` is getting replaced with `â€` character

Comment: Then it is probably not  simple dash, but a longer version.

Comment: The hyphen character is most likely unicode (perhaps `̵ ` or `‒` or `–` which is different then `-`) . This means that either your column type is `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` (ascii only instead of unicode), or your client's connection through which you submitted your SQL statement to SELECT this data is not set up to be unicode. It's trying to take a multi-byte unicode character and convert it multiple single-byte ASCII characters resulting in nonsense.

Comment: @JNevill whats the best solution then?

Comment: Just checked and copying & pasting an n-dash and m-dash from MS Word into `select dump('–') from dual` gives them as `226,128,147` and `226,128,148` respectively (i.e. three characters each). `226` on its own is `â` and 128 is `€`. Probably something else is stripping out the `147` or `148`  which would appear as double-smartquotes. More [here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

Comment: @OP, use the Translate or Replace function as noted in the answer to convert these Unicode characters to ASCII to match your session, or change your session to unicode so these characters don't get dumbed-down in transmission to your computer.

Comment: Instead of changing the values you can also configure your client application properly. Which client application do you use and what is your `NLS_LANG` value?

Comment: @JNevill, nowadays the default character set for Oracle is `AL32UTF8`, i.e. `VARCHAR2` is also capable to store any Unicode character like `NVARCHAR2` typically does.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you! Oracle is definitely not my sweet spot. I appreciate the extra info :)

Comment: Sorry for missing HEX values. Missing quotes could be because it uses a ISP-8859-x character set instead of Windows CP125x

Comment: What do you get from `select dump(column name,1016) from ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string has `CHR(226)` and `CHR(128)`.

You could use `TRANSLATE` or `REPLACE`.

```
select TRANSLATE  ( 'â€', CHR(226)||CHR(128), '-')  FROM DUAL;
```

yields `-`  ( Tested in SQL developer )

So, to update the column ( check carefully before doing this), use

```
UPDATE yourtable
    SET
        columnname = translate(columnname,CHR(226)
        || CHR(128),'-')
WHERE
    columnname LIKE '%'
    || CHR(226)
    || CHR(128)
    || '%';
```

To get a complete list of all characters and `CHR` values, use any of these.

```
SELECT
    level i,
    chr(level) str
FROM
    dual
CONNECT BY
    level <= 255;
```

OR

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..255 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(chr(i)
        || ' == '
        || i);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: what would be if I need to replace in whole column with 'hypen' instead of 'â€'

Comment: @palkodi : added a sample update statement. Take a look.

Comment: How do you know that `CHR(226) = â` and `CHR(128) = €` without knowing the database character set?